# How to use pyuic5 in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyuic

I'm trying to figure out how to use this command:

```
pyuic5
```

when I installed Python through Visual Studio 2017.

Everywhere I try it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try using the Visual Studio command line?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

go to view => other windows => python environment

[image]

```
pyuic5
```

works when you open the command prompt this way, when installing python with visual studio 2017